# Is possible to post messages or praise on Yammer using their api from my web application

Tags: c#, api, web-applications, yammer

I would like to praise people when they do something on the website at job. I have an user on yammer that I would like to use to post or praise these people (all people at job are on Yammer). I've seen from the api that we can post with it, but it seems we have to log with an application Consumer key / Secret.

Is it possible to use Yammer's api to log in with that a user and praise someone ?

Do I have to log in with the OAuth process ?

Can I use Yammer's api if my web application is not a Yammer application ?

Do I have to make my own Wrapper and retro-engineer Yammer to log in ?

Any documentation or idea would be great !

Answer (score 0):

So after research I came to the followings conclusions.

Do I have to log in with the OAuth process ? Yes.
You have to in order to get an access token. The token last forever or until the user remove your application from his applications.

Can I use Yammer's api if my web application is not a Yammer application ? No.
In order to call api you need to have an access token.

Do I have to make my own Wrapper and retro-engineer Yammer to log in ? No.
No logging is require once you have the access token. You can even post with the user logged off.